# Scrolling div using scrolltop() and div position.top only working correctly once, then strangely

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm making a scroller website, using a fixed div for the navigation, and a wrapper div as the part that is scrolled using .scrollTop on the nav click handlers.

It is working if I click the links the first time after a refresh, then subsequent use of the nav sends the scroll to somewhat random positions.

I'm thinking this might have something to do with the fact that I am using a wrapper and not using scrollTop directly on 'html, body'?

The click handlers I'm using for the nav buttons look like this:

```
    $('#mylink3').click(function() {
        $('#wrapper').animate({scrollTop: $('#environment3').position().top}, 1000);
    });
```

The test site is here:

http://testbed.shottotheface.org.

Thanks so much for any help! I'm going cross eyed on this one and it feels like it should be such a simple answer.

Cooper

[edit]

I tried removing my #wrapper and using a click handler like this:

$('#mylink2').click(function() {$('body, html').animate({scrollTop: $('#environment2').offset().top}, 1000);  });

But I don't seem to be having any luck..? I tried .offset with the #wrapper earlier today... am I still doing something wrong?

Comment: `.position` gets the position in relation to the offsetTarget of the element, which for your _environment_ elements is `#wrapper` – try using `.offset` instead, that always gets the position relative to the document. (Why are you using that wrapper element here anyway? It leads to your header element overlapping the scrollbar, which is just ugly IMHO. Your header has `position:fixed`, so why not leave the rest of the content in `body` and scroll that (or `html`) to the appropriate position in the first place? Would at least fix the overlapped-scrollbar issue.)

Comment: Thanks CBroe, I added an update above. For some reason I can't get it to scroll without the #wrapper, and the scroll bar seems to stay behind the header despite being fixed. *sigh* I wish I had more experience with DOM stuff.

Comment: Why I am not able to see any scrolling on the given site

Comment: Try it now SSS, I had implemented the previous suggestion and the scrolling stopped working, but I've reverted it back now.